# Can i use iterator within iterator on jsp in struts2.0?

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator, jsp-tags

This is the ArrayList defined in the

```
private ArrayList<LocWiseSaleParam> locWiseSaleList;

where LocWiseSaleParam is myaction class
```

I am using a iterator on jsp and accessing its values. but can i use the iterator with the same value as nested iterator

```
<s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList" id="list" >
           <s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList" id="list" >
                 <s:property value="productName"/>
           </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

It is needed to do becausse i am creating a tabular structure on jsp

Comment: I don't do Struts, but should you *logically* not be using a different `id` for each? Else the inner one may override the outer one which causes the outer one not to work anymore after first iteration.

Comment: ok that was my mistake it can be like this, mean id can be different

<s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList" id="parentList" >
           <s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList" id="childList" >
                 <s:property value="productName"/>
           </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
but value would be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this

```
<s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList" id="parent">
  <s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList">
      <s:property value="#parent.productName"/> //this will give value of parent iterator
      <s:property value="productName"/>         //this will give value of the child iterator
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

AAh,i didnt notice this post is too old

Answer (score 2):

```
<s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList" id="parent" stratus="id">
  <s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList{parent.id}">
      <s:property value="#parent.productName"/> //this will give value of parent iterator
      <s:property value="productName"/>         //this will give value of the child iterator
  </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Prepend your code with four space characters. Otherwise html/xml tags will be hidden by parser.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The nested iterator will ask the value stack for the top named iterable "locWiseSaleList" and it should find the same object. I'm not sure if a new iterator is generated on each call, but I guess it is, and then it should work.

Why don't you just try it?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the similar requirement and below one worked

```
<s:set var="temp" value="locWiseSaleList"/>
<s:iterator value="locWiseSaleList" var="i" >
       <s:iterator value="temp" var="j" >
             ${i.productName} ${j.productName} 
       </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

you can use i and j and normal loop counter variables but here i, j will hold your LocWiseSaleParam object.

and our s:set statement will create a copy of list.